# Eu estou clicando no elemento <details> ou <summary>?

Tags: html

Eu fiquei muito confuso no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary>O que é HTTPS?</summary>
        <p>
            HTTPS é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança
            que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam
            transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade
            do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.
            <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure" target="_blank">Wikipédia</a>
        </p>
    </details>
<body>
</html>
```

Pois dentro do elemento `<details>` tem o `<summary>` e o conteúdo, quando eu clico para exibir o conteúdo eu estou clicando no `<details>`? pois como o `<summary>` está dentro de `<details>` é para mim estar clicando no `<details>` já que o `<details>` é pai de `<summary>`, mas o conteúdo do `<summary>` é exibido na frente em qual dos dois eu estaria clicando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está clicando no `<summary>` pois assim como você disse, ele está na frente do `<details>`.

Para confirmar isso, eu alterei o código para que ao clicar em algum local da página, ele informasse o nome da tag do elemento que estou clicando.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <script>
        function show(){
            alert(document.activeElement.tagName);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onclick="show()">
    <details>
        <summary>O que é HTTPS?</summary>
        <p>
            HTTPS é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança
            que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam
            transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade
            do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.
            <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure" target="_blank">Wikipédia</a>
        </p>
    </details>
<body>
</html>
```

Ao clicar no elemento, ele emite um alerta informando que o elemento ativo é o `SUMMARY`. Porém ao remover a tag `<summary>` não haverá mais nenhum outro elemento na frente do `<details>`, assim sendo, ele irá informar `DETAILS`.

Comment: Continuo não entendendo, no caso do seu código quando o `details` é aberto é retornado `SUMMARY`, mas ao clicar no conteúdo já aberto é retornado `BODY` sendo que eu estou clicando no `details`.

Comment: @joãobatista basta ler sobre document.activeElement, se você não procura entender o básico do DOM ai vc se perde mesmo, o activeElement é uma referencia aos elementos que podem receber foco do ponteiro, como botões, campos de texto e links (e o proprio summary). Logo ao clicar em outra área só retorna BODY porque outros elementos não são "focaveis", ai só sobra o foco padrão quando você clica em algo que não aceita foco, o padrão é BODY. De qualquer forma a resposta do Jean foi para explicar que sim, você clica no summary e não no DETAILS.

Comment: Foi mal cara, é que eu estou iniciando nesses negócios e não entendo muito bem como funciona as coisas.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro deve saber que os eventos do JavaScript são propagados para os elementos pais, ou seja, ao clicar em `<sumary>` você também está clicando em `<details>`, já que o primeiro é filho do segundo. Então você não está clicando em um ou outro mas sim em ambos

```html
<script>
    function log(el){
        console.log(`O elemento ${el} foi clicado`);
    }
</script>
<details onclick="log('details')">
    <summary onclick="log('summary')">O que é HTTPS?</summary>
    <p onclick="log('p')">
        HTTPS é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança
        que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam
        transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade
        do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.
        <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure" target="_blank">Wikipédia</a>
    </p>
</details>
```

Mas você pode parar a propagação do evento e impedir que os elementos pais de receber o click:

```html
<script>
    function log(event, el, stop){
        console.log(`O elemento ${el} foi clicado`);
        if (stop) event.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>
<details onclick="log(event, 'details')">
    <summary onclick="log(event, 'summary', true)">O que é HTTPS?</summary>
    <p onclick="log(event, 'p', false)">
        HTTPS é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança
        que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam
        transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade
        do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.
        <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure" target="_blank">Wikipédia</a>
    </p>
</details>
```

Se quer saber qual foi o peimeiro elemento a ser clicado ("o elemento mais abaixo"), pode acessar a propriedade `target` do evento:

```html
<script>
    function log(event){
        console.log(`O primeiro elemento clicado foi ${event.target.tagName}`);
    }
</script>
<details onclick="log(event)">
    <summary>O que é HTTPS?</summary>
    <p>
        HTTPS é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança
        que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam
        transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade
        do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.
        <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure" target="_blank">Wikipédia</a>
    </p>
</details>
```